# How can I output to the console all addresses of available local interfaces?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a local network interfaces:
127.0.0.1,
192.168.0.73

If I use the following code:

```
std::string local_address = "";
std::string local_port= "80";
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_executors_);
ba::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(local_address, local_port);
local_endpoint_it_ = resolver.resolve(query);

for(auto it = local_endpoint_it_; it != ba::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->endpoint() << std::endl;
```

When `local_address` = `""`, I can only see:

```
[:: 1]:80, 
127.0.0.1:80
```

When `local_address` = `"0.0.0.0"`, I only see:

```
0.0.0.0:80
```

When `local_address` = `"192.168.0.73"`, I see:

```
192.168.0.73:80
```

How do I get all the addresses of my local interfaces, if at this time I do not know their addresses?

An example output must be:

```
127.0.0.1:80, 
192.168.0.73:80 
and may be [:: 1]: 80
```

Comment: @John Zwinck  Thanks! May be it can be done by using boost::asio (crossplatform and as usual with a little bit more friendly interface)?

Comment: People wanted the same thing five years ago too, but it seems nothing has changed: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a C++ wrapper for `getifaddrs` here: http://vrjuggler.org/docs/vapor/2.2/programmer.reference/namespacevpr.html#aadd07b8751f2d2ba6b757e9c11fd7eab

It's not part of Boost Asio, but that project uses Boost and implements this itself, so hopefully you'll find it suitable.

Comment: The link is dead now, look here https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/vrjuggler/blob/master/modules/vapor/vpr/md/common/InetAddrHelpers.cpp